# In android, how to load multiple screen within a single screen using different action buttons

Tags: android

I am working on this app wherein i have to load multiple screens which are control using button click in landscape view. For eg. Let us assume at the top of the screen i have three buttons- day,month and week calender view. So on the day button click, i should be able to load multiple screen fragments say for today,yesterday and tomorrow schedules at the middle of same screen, similarly on the month button click, i should be able to see grid view of schedule for the whole month. So please help me out how to achieve this, on the same screen. I want to optimize the code and re use the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Yes i have gone through the developer sites on fragment but still i am confused in understanding what layout need to be use for the screen and as the middle screen going to change according to the button clicks. How to handle dynamic loading of fragments. How activity going to take care of these fragments. All sorts of questions running through my mind.

Comment: You need to read all about layouts on the developer site and there is a lot of trial and error involved. Linear layout for fragments will do but you have to do it yourself. There is no shortcut for beginners.

Comment: You might wanna look for relevant existing projects or solutions on the web like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042510/change-android-layout-with-fragments